# What is the best technique to find two duplicate values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to find two adjacent elements == 1:2 or 1:3 in array,
trigger needed for not count third element
Its works as it should, but its looks ugly, how I can optimize it?
May be I can skip next iteration in each, but how?

```
history["1:2", "1:11", "1:9", "1:6", "1:9", "1:2", "1:3", "1:10", "1:9", "1:3", "1:3"];

function getStats(history) {

    trigger = 0;
    dfault1 = 0;

    $.each(history, function(index, value) {
        if (((history[index] == '1:2') || (history[index] == '1:3'))  && ((history[index+1] == '1:2') || (history[index+1] == '1:3'))  ) {
            if (trigger == 0) {
                dfault1++;
                trigger = 1;
            } else {
                trigger = 0;
            }
        } else { 
           trigger = 0; 
        }
    });
    console.log(dfault1);
}
```

dfault1 = 2 couz

```
history[5] = '1:2' && history[6] = '1:3' dfault++ (1)
```

then

```
history[9] = '1:3' && history[10] = '1:3' dfault++ (2)
```

p.s. sry for my English, if you didnt understand - tell me, I will correct my question

Comment: It's not so clear what you're asking.  Are you trying to figure out if there are multiple `1:2` objects in the array?  Or are you trying to find objects that are adjacent to each other?

Comment: ( (array[X] = '1:2') || (array[X] = '1:3') ) AND ( (array[X+1] = '1:2') || (array[X+1] = '1:3') ) but every element counts only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to clean it up.

```
function getStats(history) {
    matches = function(value) {
        return value == "1:2" || value == "1:3";
    };

    default1 = 0;
    prev = null;
    $.each(history, function(index, value) {
        if (matches(value) && matches(prev)) {
            default1++;
            prev = null;
            return true;
        }
        prev = value;
    });

    console.log(default1);
}
```